# Sort map using comparator not working properly

Tags: java

I'm having a map(this comes directly from the web service, so the input is map anyways) and I'm trying to sort the map based on description. But, two keys are having empty description and they are required anyhow now. When I sort one key goes on missing and one key with empty description is available. Here is my code

```
public class TestArabic {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Map<Integer, NationalityDto> m = new HashMap<Integer, NationalityDto>();

    NationalityDto n10 = new NationalityDto();
    n10.setNatid(110);
    n10.setDesc("");
    m.put(110, n10);

    NationalityDto n2 = new NationalityDto();
    n2.setNatid(102);
    n2.setDesc("الهند");
    m.put(102, n2);
    NationalityDto n3 = new NationalityDto();
    n3.setNatid(103);
    n3.setDesc("سعودي");
    m.put(103, n3);
    NationalityDto n1 = new NationalityDto();
    n1.setNatid(101);
    n1.setDesc("مصر");
    m.put(101, n1);
    NationalityDto n4 = new NationalityDto();
    n4.setNatid(104);
    n4.setDesc("الكويت");
    m.put(104, n4);
    NationalityDto n5 = new NationalityDto();
    n5.setNatid(105);
    n5.setDesc("لبنان");
    m.put(105, n5);
    NationalityDto n6 = new NationalityDto();
    n6.setNatid(106);
    n6.setDesc("");
    m.put(106, n6);
    System.out.println("Actual map");
    System.out.println(m);

    Map<Integer, NationalityDto> sortedMap = sortByValue(m);



    System.out.println("About to sort the map");
    System.out.println(sortedMap);
    List<NationalityDto> list = new ArrayList<>();

    //Add elements
    for(Map.Entry<Integer, NationalityDto> m1 : sortedMap.entrySet()) {
        list.add(m1.getValue());
    }

    Collections.sort(list, (e1, e2) -> e1.getDesc().compareTo(e2.getDesc()));

    Map<Integer, NationalityDto> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    for(NationalityDto dto : list){
        map.put(dto.getNatid(), dto);
    }
    System.out.println("Sorted map");
    System.out.println(map);

}

private static Map<Integer, NationalityDto> sortByValue(Map m) {
    Map<Integer, NationalityDto> sortedMap = new TreeMap(new ValueComparator(m));
    sortedMap.putAll(m);
    return sortedMap;
}
}

class ValueComparator implements Comparator<Integer> {
Map<Integer, NationalityDto> map;

public ValueComparator(Map map) {
    this.map = map;
}

public int compare(Integer s1, Integer s2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return ((NationalityDto) map.get(s1)).getDesc().compareTo(((NationalityDto) map.get(s2)).getDesc());
}
}
```

### Output

```
{101=NationalityDto [natid=101, desc=مصر], 102=NationalityDto [natid=102, desc=الهند], 103=NationalityDto [natid=103, desc=سعودي], 104=NationalityDto [natid=104, desc=الكويت], 105=NationalityDto [natid=105, desc=لبنان], 106=NationalityDto [natid=106, desc=], 110=NationalityDto [natid=110, desc=]}

About to sort the map

{106=NationalityDto [natid=110, desc=], 104=NationalityDto [natid=104, desc=الكويت], 102=NationalityDto [natid=102, desc=الهند], 103=NationalityDto [natid=103, desc=سعودي], 105=NationalityDto [natid=105, desc=لبنان], 101=NationalityDto [natid=101, desc=مصر]}

Sorted map

{110=NationalityDto [natid=110, desc=], 104=NationalityDto [natid=104, desc=الكويت], 102=NationalityDto [natid=102, desc=الهند], 103=NationalityDto [natid=103, desc=سعودي], 105=NationalityDto [natid=105, desc=لبنان], 101=NationalityDto [natid=101, desc=مصر]}
```

Now 106 key is missing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *cannot sort a `TreeMap` by value.*  Anyone who told you you could was wrong, and the value comparator you have used is broken.

The only valid way of sorting a map by value is the one you've used in your `main` method: sort the entries as a list and dump into a `LinkedHashMap`.

```
for(Map.Entry<Integer, NationalityDto> m1 : sortedMap.entrySet()) {
    list.add(m1.getValue());
}

Collections.sort(list, (e1, e2) -> e1.getDesc().compareTo(e2.getDesc()));

Map<Integer, NationalityDto> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();

for(NationalityDto dto : list){
    map.put(dto.getNatid(), dto);
```

This part will sort the entries if you don't give it a broken map in the first place.  Your `sortByValue` method is broken; don't use it.

Comment: I'm doing it Map<Integer, NationalityDto> sortedMap = sortByValue(m);? Do you mean this one?

Comment: Yes.  And your `sortByValue` method doesn't work.  `new TreeMap(new HackToTryToMakeTreeMapCompareValues())` _doesn't_ work.

Comment: you are also using sortedMap(this is coming from sortByValue method)  for iteration. Plz post the snippet after creatin the map

Comment: Got your point. Instead of sortedMap, I should use the original map.

Comment: Yes.  Delete your `sortByValue` method.